# counting DISTINCT copies of row elements

Tags: arrays, numpy

Consider the array sample A.

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[2, 3, 6, 7, 3, 6, 7, 2],
              [2, 3, 6, 7, 3, 6, 7, 7],
              [2, 4, 3, 4, 6, 4, 9, 4],
              [4, 9, 0, 1, 2, 5, 3, 0],
              [5, 5, 2, 5, 4, 3, 7, 5],
              [7, 5, 4, 8, 0, 1, 2, 6],
              [7, 5, 4, 7, 3, 8, 0, 7]])
```

PROBLEM: I want to identify rows that have a specified number of DISTINCT element copies.  The following code comes close:  **The code needs to be able to answer questions like "which rows of A have exactly 4 elements that appear twice?", or "which rows of A have exactly 1 element that appear three times?"**

```
r,c = A.shape
nCopies = 4
s = np.sort(A,axis=1)
out = A[((s[:,1:] != s[:,:-1]).sum(axis=1)+1 == c - nCopies)]
```

This produces 2 output rows, both having 4 copied elements.
The 1st row has copies of 2,3,6,7.   The 2nd row has copies of 3,6,7,7:

```
array([[2, 3, 6, 7, 3, 6, 7, 2],
       [2, 3, 6, 7, 3, 6, 7, 7]])
```

My problem is that I don't want the 2nd output row because it only has 3 DISTINCT copies (ie: 3,6,7)
How can to code be modified to identify only distinct copies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the rows of A that have 4 distinct values and every value must have at least one copy. You can leverage `np.unique(return_counts=True)` which returns 2 values, the distinct values and the count of each value.

```
counts = [np.unique(row,return_counts=True) for row in A ]
valid_indices = [ np.all(row[1] > 1) and row[0].shape[0] == 4 for row in counts ]
valid_rows = A[valid_indices]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.   The code produced the correct output when looking for 4 DISTINCT values that are copied, but that was an unfortunate result of the fact that the rows of A have 8 elements.   I should have been clearer.   Your approach seems great, but how could the valid_indices line be modified to do this:  valid_indices = ["row[1] holds exactly 4 values of 2"].  That way, I could also use your solution to answer questions like   valid_indices = ["'row[1] holds exactly 3 values of 2 "],   or  even valid_indices = ["'row[1] holds exactly 1 value of 3"'].   Thank you.

Comment: This is essentially Many Valdez's solution, but it has been generalized a bit by changing the valid line:
# for exactly 4 PAIRS of unique values,  
**valid = [np.any(np.count_nonzero(row[1] == 2) == 4) for row in count]** 
# for exactly 1 TRIPLE of unique values,  
**valid = [np.any(np.count_nonzero(row[1] == 3) == 1) for row in count]**